# Array modification while iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

When trying to modify the current item while iterating over an array the modification fails. Below is the sample code.

```
var s_arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];
var arr = [];

for(var i in s_arr) {

  if(s_arr[i].a == 5) {

    s_arr[i].b = 0;
    console.log('First modification: ' +JSON.stringify(s_arr[i]));
    arr.push(s_arr[i]);

    s_arr[i].b = 9;
    console.log('Second modification: ' +JSON.stringify(s_arr[i]));
    arr.push(s_arr[i]);
  }

}

console.log('Final: ' +JSON.stringify(arr));
```

After running the above script `node test.js`, below is the result.

```
First modification: {"a":5,"b":0}
Second modification: {"a":5,"b":9}
Final: [{"a":5,"b":9},{"a":5,"b":9}]
```

Expected result is as below.

```
First modification: {"a":5,"b":0}
Second modification: {"a":5,"b":9}
Final: [{"a":5,"b":0},{"a":5,"b":9}]
```

However when adding new object while iteration & assigning each values of current item (object) extensively works.

```
var s_arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];
var arr = [];

for(var i in s_arr) {

  if(s_arr[i].a == 5) {

    s_arr[i].b = 9;
    console.log('Second modification: ' +JSON.stringify(s_arr[i]));
    arr.push(s_arr[i]);

    var a = {};
    a.a = s_arr[i].a;
    a.b = 0;
    arr.push(a);

    var b = {};
    b.a = s_arr[i].a;
    b.b = 9;
    arr.push(b);
  }

}

console.log('Final: ' +JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Below is the result of modified script.

```
Final: [{"a":5,"b":0},{"a":5,"b":9}]
```

Why is the first script when ran shows modification of object right but the final array shows which consists of modified objects is not as expected?

Comment: maybe because it's the same object  ? .. it's not pushing a copy of this object in the array, so you add the same reference to the object twice.

Comment: Objects always passed by reference, you should clone it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects always passed by reference in JS.

`arr.push(s_arr[i]);` does not create copy of object, it just save reference to it in the `arr` array;
So any changes inside object you will see in the array too.

You should explicit clone your object to prevent changes.
 For example you can use `serialize-deserialize` pair:

```
arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s_arr[i])));
```

---

Your

```
var a = {};
a.a = s_arr[i].a;
a.b = 0;
arr.push(a);
```

will work too, because you create new object instance here and use **only scalar** properties to fill it.